# Is y at the end of muddy derivational

Tags: morphology

***Mud*** is the root word. If I add ***-dy*** to make the word ***muddy***, is that suffix a derivational or inflectional morpheme?

Comment: That's a 'derivational morpheme' because it does change the part of speech of the word. 'Mud' is a noun and 'muddy' is an adjective. (BTW, the suffix is *-y*, not *-ddy*.)

Comment: Right. It's derivational. Here's [a handout on the subject](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The suffix in the word *muddy* is ***-y***, which is an adjective-forming suffix usually added to nouns and verbs. The root word in *muddy* is *mud*.

'**Inflectional morphemes**' are ones that don't change the part of speech of a word, for instance, the plural suffix *-s* or the past tense marker *-ed*:

- bag → bag**s** (both are nouns)
- want → want**s**, want**ed** (all of them are verbs)

'**Derivational morphemes**' on the other hand are ones that do change the part of speech of a word. For example, suffixes like *-y*, *-ise/-ize* etc:

- mud (noun) → mudd**y** (adj)
- standard (noun or adj) → standard**ise** (verb)

Comment: See also _slime, slimy; haste, hasty; fish, fishy; health, healthy,_ ...